# Flutter package for recognising multiple faces in a CCTV video

Tags: flutter, deep-learning, computer-vision, face-recognition

I was building a flutter app that could be used as a phone CCTV video camera. I started looking for packages that could help me build it. Came across Google_mlkit_face_detection, flutter_face_detector, etc. But all of those are used for detection purposes and not for recognition. I have a database containing people’s faces. If a face from the Flutter app’s video matches the face in the database, then their names should be added to a list.
I tried using Python on a server for this, but it isn’t efficient at times.

Can you help me with a Flutter package that could help me build this? (Non depreciated ones)